# sending empty data to api

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm learning angluar and have following problem:

my web api awaits this dto:

```
 public int? Id{get;set;}
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string DisplayName{get;set;}
    public char? Gender{get;set;}
```

and i try send it from my angular app:

```
export interface UserDto {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  birthDate?: Date;
  gender?: string;
}
```

and i send it by this:

```
const endpoint = ApiQueryService.ApiEndpoint + this.postUserEndpoint;
    let result: number;
    this.client.post<number>(endpoint, {body: JSON.stringify(dto.userDto)}).subscribe(x =>
      result = x);
```

i event tried to null datetime field:

```
dto.userDto.birthDate = null;
```

but my web api always retrieve null from this api...

api works correct, i have 2 other clients which are works

my api returns Created[image]

what am i doing wrong?

and second question:
how can i also get whole HttpResponse from server
how

Comment: Does your backend really expects an object with a single property named "body"? Because that's what your frontend is sending. Use the "Network" tab of your browser dev tools, and you'll see what you're sending.

Comment: event if i send it as "userDto" or without this i still get null's in api

Comment: and yet you accepted the answer telling the same thing as my comment, so... I guess it worked after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think you don't need to wrap your DTO in another object or stringify it. Could your try :

```
this.client.post<number>(endpoint, dto.userDto).subscribe(x =>
  result = x)
```